# Django, append value to a foreing key list

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

I have set the following model structure:

```
class Prodotto(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Nome del Prodotto', max_length=30)

class ProdottoFilter(models.Model):
    prodotto=models.ForeignKey(Prodotto, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

After that I have created a form using the ProdottoFilter model.
Here my views.py:

```
...
if request.method == 'POST':
         form = ProdottoFilterForm(request.POST)
         if form.is_valid():
             prodotto = form.save()
    else :
        form = ProdottoFilterForm()
```

Now I want to appened a value to the variable `prodotto`, ad example the value "Tutti i prodotti".

I have tried:

```
a="Tutti i prodotti"
prodotto.insert(0,a)
```

But python give me the following error:

```
'ProdottoFilter' object has no attribute 'insert'
```

Comment: can you show the code of `prodotto` assignement? It's not clear if this is queryset or list.

Answer (score 0):

1. Save the `ProdottoFilter` model instance.
2. Create a `Prodotto` model instance.
3. Assign string to `name` attribute and save `Prodotto` instance.
4. Attach foreign key.
5. Save `ProdottoFilter` instance

```py
prodottofilter = form.save()
prodotto = Prodotto(name="Tutti i prodotti")
prodotto.save()
prodottofilter.prodotto = prodotto
prodottofilter.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

`prodotto` is an instance of `ProdottoFilter` model so if you want to assign a new `Prodotto` then you may do the following code:

```
...
prodotto_filter = form.save()
prodotto_filter.prodotto = Prodotto.objects.create(name='Tutti i prodotti')
prodotto_filter.save()
...
```

Note that I've renamed the variable to be more consistent with the object type.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to supplement the other answers. You can also use `add` method this way:

```py
# In views.py - at if form.is_valid(): block.
prodotto_filter = form.save()
prodotto = Prodotto.objects.create(name='Tutti i prodotti')
prodotto.prodottofilter_set.add(prodotto)
```

Maybe this approach represents the 'append value to a foreing key list' idea better. You can read more about the method here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add
Also you can change the default `prodottofilter_set` name by setting the `related_name` parameter in the ForeignKey definition this way:

```py
# in models.py
class ProdottoFilter(models.Model):
    prodotto=models.ForeignKey(Prodotto, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='filters')

# In views.py - at if form.is_valid(): block.
prodotto_filter = form.save()
prodotto = Prodotto.objects.create(name='Tutti i prodotti')
prodotto.filters.add(prodotto)
```

Answer (score -1):

**model.py**

```
class like(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(post,on_delete = "CASCADE")
```

**views.py**

```
def like(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        post_id = request.GET['post_id']
        likedpost = post.objects.get(id = post_id )
        m = like( post=likedpost )
        m.save()
        return HttpResponse('success')
    else:
        return HttpResponse("unsuccesful")
```